# Perl: Removing leftover anchor tags from a string

Tags: html, regex, perl

I wrote a script to check all URLs in an HTML file and remove them with HTTP::Tiny and delete, but it left a bunch of incomplete anchor tags like `<a>text here</a>` throughout the database. These changes have already been made and the script doesn't need to be run again.

The script read from a database where this info is stored.

The goal now is to strip the `<a>text here</a>` while leaving everything else in the buffer plus the "text here" text.

I wrote another script that reads the database and includes the following regex:

```
$html_buffer =~ s/(.*?)<a>(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)/$1$2$3/g;
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Here's an example buffer:

```
This week, perhaps the most interesting articles include &quot;<a>Finding \r\n  that Windows is superior to Linux is biased</a>,&quot; &quot;<a href=\"http://www.example.com/content/view/118693\">How \r\n  to set up DNS for Linux VPNs</a>,&quot; and &quot;<a href=\"http://www.example.com/content/view/118664
\">Writing \r\n  an Incident Handling and Recovery Plan</a>.&quot;
```

Of course I want the regex to operate throughout the string, but also match multiple occurrences within the string.

Is this the most effective way to do this? How can I be sure to not remove the `</a>` at the end of the string like in the above example?

Comment: `(.*?)` at the end never matches anything. Also, it's not a good idea to include `\r\n` in your sample string as an example, it's not a good idea. Better to let the editor do the line feeds for you. It's clear what you mean. Also, note that the format is `///sg` for global dot includes all, which is your problem.

Comment: I am not sure with that example buffer what you need -- to remove `<a>` and its "corresponding" `</a>` (the first `</a>` that comes after that `<a>`), but to not remove `<a href=...>...</a>` -- is that right?  If it is, did you try `s{<a>(.*?)</a>}{$1}sg` ?  Works in my quick test

Comment: Another option --why not fix that script so that it doesn't leave unwanted things behind?

Comment: I've made some notes above to be more clear about the use of a database and the purpose. I'm relatively new at this. The changes were already written to the database - now I need to strip the <a> and </a> tags that have no actual link in them while leaving any tags with legitimate links in them.

Comment: @zdim - the HTTP::Tiny script has already been run on the database so it doesn't have to be run again. sin - that is just as the text appears in the buffer from the database.

Comment: Using regex to work with HTML or XML is a recipe for extreme frustration.  Regex is the wrong tool.  You need to use a real HTML parser and deal with the DOM.

Comment: @AlexRegan OK. I meant that perhaps you could re-do the job, but with that script fixed (with a proper HTML/XML parser there shouldn't be bits left around!).  On the other hand -- did you try the regex I included in that comment?  I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: zdim - it also needs to not strip the content before and after the anchor tags. Does your regex do that, or does it also need (.*?) before and after the anchor tags, like my regex is doing already? @JimGarrison yes, if there was now a DOM parser that just stripped the <a> and </a> I would use that, but HTTP::Tiny screwed me.

Comment: zdim - it actually does look like your regex worked. Would you explain how it's different from mine and how yours works? What does the last 's' do?

Comment: @AlexRegan "_HTTP::Tiny screwed me_" -- that may be worth a question in its own right, about how those `<a>text</a>` happened after processing (valid I presume) HTML

Comment: @zdim at one point I thought my regex was replacing the entire buffer with just the text within the anchor tags, so I added the (.*?) at the beginning and end, but perhaps it was because it was missing the /s that it would otherwise not print the whole string. I'll continue to investigate, and I was also thinking about posting separately about HTTP::Tiny and delete

Comment: @zdim - I just posted the question about the problematic HTTP::Tiny delete function and how it appears to leave broken anchor tags
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71007982/perl-httptiny-delete-leaves-broken-anchor-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In principle, it is **always** advisable to use a proper parser.  An example is in the second part*

---

That regex needs the `/s` modifier so that `.` matches linefeeds as well, and then it works.  Without it the pattern `.*?` stops at newlines. It's only by happenstance that the as it is regex still manages to match some of the string, appearing to "work but not right."

The point is that that string, with `\n`s in it, has newlines if it's assigned as double-quoted

```
my $html_buffer = " ... ";   # or:  = qq(...);
```

because then `\n` is interpreted as a linefeed.  If that string is given with single quotes,

```
my $html_buffer = ' ... ';   # or:  = q(...);
```

then there are no newlines in it, just occasional characters `\` and `n` one after antoher, and `.*?` works as intended.

Finally: The substitution operator affects only the part of the string that has been matched (or less, if the pattern is written so to "drop" some of the match, for example with `\K`), so there is no reason for the leading and trailing `(.*?)`.  All that's needed is

```
$html_buffer =~ s{<a>(.*?)</a>}{$1}sg;
```

And for a little extra safety add little extra spaces in all these patterns, for `<\s*a\s*>` so

```
$html_buffer =~ s{<\s*a\s*>(.*?)<\s*/a\s*>}{$1}sg;
```

---

To note, I'd find it a far superior solution to fix that original script so that it doesn't leave unintended bits and pieces behind.  I'd hazard a guess that that happened by using regex for HTML? It would be very surprising that any of the major libraries written to parse HTML/XML would cripple (valid I presume) HTML like that.

On the other hand, that can be done now, as well. If the remaining text and its not-links (`<a>` with no `href` attribute technically isn't a hyperlink) are exceedingly simple then it may be simpler to use a regex (fingers crossed) as asked; just this one time.

In all other cases, here's a very basic take with [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::DOM; 

my $html = q(<p> a link: <a>no href</a>, not. <p> OK: <a href="#">hoho</a>);

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );    
say $dom; 

foreach my $link ($dom->find("a")->each) { 

    if (not defined $link->attr->{href}) {
        # Replace this node with its text
        $link->replace( $link->text );
    }

}
say $dom;  # object stringifies to just its HTML
```

(or `$link->strip;` to remove the HTML element but leave its content, with the same result)

This prints

```
<p> a link: <a>no href</a>, not. </p><p> OK: <a href="#">hoho</a></p>
<p> a link: no href, not. </p><p> OK: <a href="#">hoho</a></p>
```

I've used a shorter made-up HTML string, but I checked with the question's example as well.  There are other ways to do this with `Mojo` and it's fun (and useful) exploring them.

For example, process only the links for which `href` attribute isn't defined, by filtering first

```
$_->replace($_->text) for 
    $dom -> find("a")
         -> grep( sub { not defined $_->attr->{href} } )
         -> each;
```

Or, process directly

```
$dom -> find("a")
     -> each( sub { 
            $_->replace($_->text) if not defined $_->attr->{href} 
        });
```