# Perl: HTTP::Tiny delete leaves broken anchor tags

Tags: html, regex, perl

I wrote a script that collects all URLs within a buffer that's read from a database, checks whether that page still exists, and uses HTTP::Tiny to delete the URL from the buffer if it is unreachable or returns invalid.

The problem is that HTTP::Tiny delete left anchor tags like text here that are invalid. The links are highlighted, but there's obviously no way to click them. Is this a deficiency with HTTP::Tiny delete or am I using it wrong?

```
my $html_full = $ref->{'fulltext'}; # $ref is a pointer to the database
my $dom_buff = Mojo::DOM->new($html_buff);
foreach my $ele ($dom_buff->find('a[href]')->each) {
  my $url = $ele->attr('href');
  my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new(default_headers => { Accept => '*/*' })->get($url);
  if ($response->{success}) {
     $success_fulltext_urls{$ref->{'id'}}{$url} = 1;
  } else {
     delete $ele->attr->{href};
     $html_buff = $dom_buff;
     $html_buff =~ s{<a>(.*?)</a>}{$1}sg;
     my $sql      = "not described here";
     write_sql($dbh,$sql,$ref->{'id'});
  }
}
```

Here is an example string, after it's been processed by the code above.

```
This week, perhaps the most interesting articles include &quot;<a>Finding \r\n  that Windows is superior to Linux is biased</a>,&quot; &quot;<a href=\"http://www.example.com/content/view/118693\">How \r\n  to set up DNS for Linux VPNs</a>,&quot; and &quot;<a href=\"http://www.example.com/content/view/118664 \">Writing \r\n  an Incident Handling and Recovery Plan</a>.&quot;
```

Note the string "Finding \r\n  that Windows is superior to Linux is biased" used to be a valid link with an href, but the delete function stripped all that out and left the anchor tags.

Is this the intended effect? Perhaps I should be using a different library or function within HTTP::Tiny?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do. I think what you want is to remove HTML links from an HTML fragment if those links are broken. You are using [`delete`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete), which removes a keys from a hash (reference) in Perl. It's a built-in and has nothing to do with HTTP::Tiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `delete` does. All your code does is remove the `href` attribute from that DOM element in your Mojo::DOM representation. It has nothing to do with HTTP::Tiny.

What you actually want to do is [call `->strip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#strip) on the `<a>` element, which removes it from the DOM, but keeps its content intact.

Since you are already using Mojo::DOM, you can just as well use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent). There is no need to pull in another UA module. You've already got the whole Mojolicious installed anyway.

You can use [a HEAD request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) rather than a GET request to check if a resource is available. There is no need to download the whole thing, the headers are sufficient.

Your code (without the DB part) can be reduced to this.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<DATA>);

foreach my $element ($dom->find('a[href]')->each) {
    $element->strip
        unless $ua->head($element->attr('href'))->res->is_success;
}

print $dom;

__DATA__
This <a href="http://example.org">link works</a>.
This <a href="http://httpstat.us/404">one does not</a>!
```

This outputs:

```
This <a href="http://example.org">link works</a>. This one does not!
```